# C++\CLI Sorting a 2-D List based on the value of the first index?

Tags: list, sorting, c++-cli

How to sort a 2-D List based on the value of the first index of the sub-list?

Say I have a 2-D List "lst" that contains the following values:

`List<List<int>^>^:
    {
    {3, 1, 3},
    {2, 5, 6},
    {1, 4, 3}
    }`

After the sort, "lst[0]" should be "{1, 4, 3}" and "lst[0][0]" should be "1". How to do that? I am using C++\CLI, not C#, unfortunately. Thanks in advance.

Comment: By "2D list", do you mean a `List<List<int>>`? Or whatever the C++/CLI syntax is for that.

Comment: @JimMischel Yes, its like List<List<int>^>^ or List<List<String^>^>^. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not great with C++/CLI, so take this with a grain of salt.

I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/15974889/56778 gives the basic idea. Modified for your lists, it would be something like:

```
static int AnonymousMethod1(List<int>^ p1, List<int>^ p2)
{
    return p1[0].CompareTo(p2[0]);
}

Comparison<List<int>^> ^ comparisonDelegate = gcnew Comparison<List<int>^>(&AnonymousMethod1);
lstTest->Sort(comparisonDelegate);
```

Comment: Thanks. Marked as answered.